# How do I switch back to a view, without it being reset, regarding programming for IOS?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am programming in xCode and one of my Nib/Xib files has some buttons that get hidden and revealed depending on the situation. It also has buttons that take it to different Nib/Xib files. Any tips on what code I should use to ensure that the buttons that were hidden/revealed in the first Nib/Xib file remain that way if I switch to a new Nib/Xib file and back again?

The way I have been coding so far (I'm very much a beginner), I reload a view each time I go to it and it resets to it's initial state.

The code I am using at the moment is basically as follows:

```
- (IBAction)backToHomeView:(id)sender {
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.homeViewController;
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

}

I hope that wasn't too confusing, let me know if I need to elaborate more.
thanks and best regards.

Comment: This depends on what you're doing in order to show/hide your view controller. Some methods keep it in memory while others will release the instance from memory.

Comment: which code do you have implemented for switching back to a view? please mention here so we can help you.

Comment: I edited my original post Pratik.

Comment: why you set windows root view controller again? use navigation controller and for going next page use push and for back to view use pop so your view will not reset

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to avoid using your views to keep track of application state. If the "situation" changes, either because of user actions or due to external factors like sensor readings, time elapsing, data received, etc., your app should be keeping track of that and updating the views accordingly. If you can do that, it doesn't matter whether views maintain their state or not -- you should update them to the current app state when they're about to be displayed (`-viewWillAppear`).

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I think I shall give it a shot by "keeping track and updating views accordingly", which is the same as the "state data model" if I understood that correctly. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `UINavigationController` and *push* the other views onto it, the parent view should not change. This is the standard way to solve this particular problem.

The other way is to persist the state of your buttons with some kind of state data model and make sure the state is set correctly before the view appears on screen.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I think I shall give it a shot by "keeping track and updating views accordingly", which is the same as the "state data model" if I understood that correctly. thanks again